# Are there any free, high quality, career mode games for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, games

One of the most frustrating things about gaming on Linux is that every game with some semblance of quality requires me to play with a bunch of obnoxious people online. Are there any free Linux games, with some degree of quality, that allow the player to play offline in a "career mode"?

Comment: neverball? It is of good quality, free, and quite playable. I don't know what career mode means -- google search gave links to some sports games -- so this could be way off ...

Comment: @taneli: career mode == story mode. In other words, there is a story to the game, and you either play through levels or through missions (like in the Need For Speed series) with a progressing score, etc. Normally in career mode games you play offline.

Comment: Both Firefox and Chrome are giving me an error when I try to upload an image jpg, jpeg or png. Have not tried other.

Comment: Some of the Humble Bundle games got open sourced after the campaigns. I don't remember which ones, but all of them have a single player and are good quality.

Comment: Nethack: Graphics - 0/10

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**0 A.D.**

- Info - A.D. ("Zero ey dee") is a historical Real Time Strategy game currently under development by Wildfire Games. As the military leader of an ancient civilisation, you must gather the resources you need to raise a military force capable of dominating your enemies.
- PlayDeb - http://www.playdeb.net/software/0%20A.D.
- Official Site - http://www.wildfiregames.com/0ad/
- Graphics - 10/10
- Developers - http://trac.wildfiregames.com/wiki/GettingStartedProgrammers
- Size - 260 MB

[image]

Answer (score 18):

**Battle for Wesnoth**

- Info - The Battle for Wesnoth is a Free, turn-based tactical strategy game with a high fantasy theme, featuring both single-player, and online/hotseat multiplayer combat. Fight a desperate battle to reclaim the throne of Wesnoth, or take hand in any number of other adventures..
- Playdeb - Not Yet Available
- Official Site - http://www.wesnoth.org/
- Graphics - 6/10
- Developers - http://wiki.wesnoth.org/Support
- Size - 280 MB

[image: Battle for Wesnoth]

Comment: Is this like a Warcraft clone or something?

Comment: @Svish: No, it's turn-based.

Answer (score 10):

**FREE CIV**

- Info - Freeciv is a Free and Open Source empire-building strategy game inspired by the history of human civilization. The game commences in prehistory and your mission is to lead your tribe from the Stone Age to the Space Age...
- PlayDeb - http://www.playdeb.net/software/FreeCiv
- Official Site - http://www.freeciv.org/
- Graphics - 4/10
- Developers - http://freeciv.wikia.com/wiki/Contacts
- Size - 15 MB

[image]

Comment: Is there a campaign or career mode for FreeCiv?

Comment: @Tim: to my memory you can play campaigns (haven't played in a while).

Answer (score 8):

**WARZONE 2100**

- Info - In Warzone 2100, you command the forces of The Project in a battle to rebuild the world after mankind has almost been destroyed by nuclear missiles. The game offers campaign, multi-player, and single-player skirmish modes. An extensive tech tree with over 400 different technologies, combined with the unit design system, allows for a wide variety of possible units and tactics.
- PlayDeb - http://www.playdeb.net/software/Warzone2100
- Official Site - http://wz2100.net/
- Graphics - 8/10
- Developers - http://developer.wz2100.net/
- Size - 63MB

[image]

Comment: I love Warzone! I play it on the PC. It has lots of upgrade options, lots of user-supplied maps, and gets good support. It's very replayable.

Answer (score 2):

**FREE DROID RPG**

- Info - The game tells the story of a world destroyed by a conflict between robots and their human masters. Play as Tux in a quest to save the world from the murderous rebel bots who know no mercy. You get to choose which path you wish to follow, and freedom of choice is everywhere in the game.

  FreedroidRPG features a real time combat system with melee and ranged weapons, fairly similar to the proprietary game Diablo. There is an innovative system of programs that can be run in order to take control of enemy robots, alter their behavior, or improve one's characteristics. You can use over 50 different kinds of items and fight countless enemies on your way to your destiny. An advanced dialog system provides story background and immersive role playing situations.

  The game is complete, fully playable, and can provide about 10 hours of fun. It is still being actively developed, and help is welcome in many areas. People having - or trying to acquire - programming, map editing, or writing skills will find FreedroidRPG to be an exciting, fast-moving project in which they can fully express their creativity.
- PlayDeb - http://www.playdeb.net/software/Freedroid%20RPG
- Official Site - http://freedroid.sourceforge.net/
- Graphics - 6/10
- Developers - http://www.freedroid.org/developer-area/contribute/
- Size - 170 MB

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**FREE ORION**

- PlayDeb - http://www.playdeb.net/software/FreeOrion
- Official Site - http://www.freeorion.org/
- Graphics - 5/10

Answer (score 2):

**MEGAGLEST**

- Info - MegaGlest is a free and open source 3D real-time strategy (RTS) game, where you control the armies of one of seven different factions: Tech, Magic, Egyptians, Indians, Norsemen, Persian or Romans. The game is setup in one of 16 naturally looking settings, which -like the unit models- are crafted with great appreciation for detail. Additional game data can be downloaded from within the game at no cost.
- PlayDeb - http://www.playdeb.net/software/megaglest
- Official Site - http://megaglest.org/
- Graphics - 8/10
- Developers - http://megaglest.org/development.html
- Size - 220 MB

[image: A group of Norsemens' Valkyrie attacking the Tech base]

Answer (score 2):

**UFO ALIEN INVASION (UFO-AI)**

- PlayDeb - http://www.playdeb.net/software/UFO%20Alien%20Invasion
- Official Site - http://ufoai.ninex.info/wiki/index.php/News
- Graphics - 7/10

Answer (score 2):

**WIDELANDS**

- PlayDeb - http://www.playdeb.net/software/Widelands
- Official Site - http://www.widelands.org/
- Graphics - 6/10

Answer (score 2):

[Oolite](http://www.oolite.org/) is a copy of [Elite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elite_%28video_game%29) - it doesn't have a story but you definitely have a career.

Answer (score 1):

**8 KINGDOMS**

- PlayDeb - http://www.playdeb.net/software/8Kingdoms
- Official Site - http://kralovstvi.sourceforge.net/
- Graphics - 5/10

Answer (score 1):

**BOS WARS**

- PlayDeb - http://www.playdeb.net/software/Bos%20Wars
- Official Site - http://www.boswars.org/
- Graphics - 5/10

Answer (score 1):

**FREE COL**

- PlayDeb - http://www.playdeb.net/software/FreeCol
- Official Site - http://www.freecol.org/
- Graphics - 4/10

Answer (score 0):

**FALL OF IMIRYN**

- PlayDeb - http://www.playdeb.net/software/Fall%20of%20Imiryn
- Official Site - http://annchienta.sourceforge.net/?page=fall_of_imiryn
- Graphics - 5/10

Answer (score 0):

**TRIPLEA**

- PlayDeb - http://www.playdeb.net/software/TripleA
- Official Site - http://triplea.sourceforge.net/
- Graphics - 4/10

Answer (score 0):

**ZOD**

- PlayDeb - http://www.playdeb.net/software/Zod
- Official Site - http://zod.sourceforge.net/
- Graphics - 5/10